# ConTeXt: How to reduce the width of a \textbackground environment?

Tags: context, two-column, width, quoting

## Given

A `\definetextbackground` named `blockquote` is defined as follows:

```
\setupwhitespace[big]

\definetextbackground[blockquote][
  location=paragraph,
  style=italicbold,
  backgroundcolor=lightgray,
  backgroundoffset=1em,
  %width=\textwidth-2em,
  before={\setupscale[maxwidth=\textwidth]},
  frame=off,
  ]

\starttext
\startcolumns[n=2, rule=on]

\input douglas

\startblockquote
\input lorem
\stopblockquote

\input knuth

\stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

[image: width]

## Question

The naively commented `width=\textwidth-2em` more or less expresses what is desired namely:

> The goal is to achieve a reduction of the `blockquote` environment with `2em`. That would result in the `backgroundcolor` area and its preceding normal paragraph being equal in width; much like this very StackExchange blockquote.

Defining everything in a single `blockquote` environment (though not necessarily a `\definetextbackground`) is essential for its projected use as a template for [Pandoc Markdown](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html).

finally, I have been experimenting with the [`\scale`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/textwidth) command but alas to no effect.

## Caveat: offset

There are two ways of defining offset: a single `backgroundoffset` as above, or `topoffset`, `bottomoffset`, `leftoffset` & `rightoffset` as shown below. The results are different. The problem with the latter method is that **columns break rather ugly without any offset.** This should be avoided. Otherwise, I am agnostic towards any particular offset method.

```
\setupwhitespace[big]

\definetextbackground[blockquote][
  location=paragraph,
  style=italicbold,
  backgroundcolor=lightgray,
  topoffset=1.25ex, bottomoffset=2ex,
  leftoffset=1.5em, rightoffset=1.5em,
  before={\setupscale[maxwidth=\textwidth]},
  frame=off,
  ]

\starttext
\startcolumns[n=2, rule=on]

\input douglas

\startblockquote
\input lorem
\stopblockquote

\input knuth

\stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

[image: column break without offset[2]]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I understand the question correctly.  You can modify the background to your liking using MetaFun.  Here I add a topoffset only for the first block and a bottomoffset only for the last block in the frame.

```
\setupwhitespace[big]

\startuseMPgraphic{custombg}
begingroup;
    save p; path p;
    for i=1 upto nofmultipars :
        p := ( llcorner multipars[i]
            -- lrcorner multipars[i]
            -- urcorner multipars[i]
            -- ulcorner multipars[i]
            -- cycle )
        enlarged (boxfilloffset,0)
        if multilocs[i] = 1: % first block
            topenlarged boxfilloffset
        elseif multilocs[i] = 3: % last block
            bottomenlarged boxfilloffset
        fi;

        if boxlinetype>0 :
            draw p boxlineoptions;
        fi;
        if boxfilltype>0 :
            fill p boxfilloptions;
        fi;
    endfor ;
endgroup;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\definetextbackground
  [blockquote]
  [location=paragraph,
   style=italicbold,
   width=\textwidth,
   mp=custombg,
   backgroundcolor=lightgray,
   backgroundoffset=1em,
   frame=off]

\starttext
\startcolumns[n=2, rule=on]

  \samplefile{knuth}
  \samplefile{knuth}
  \samplefile{knuth}

  \startblockquote
    \samplefile{knuth}
    \samplefile{knuth}
    \samplefile{knuth}
    \samplefile{knuth}
    \samplefile{knuth}
    \samplefile{knuth}
    \samplefile{knuth}
  \stopblockquote

  \samplefile{knuth}
  \samplefile{knuth}

\stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the behavior you are trying to avoid is caused by the `backgroundoffset=1em` option. You might be looking for `leftoffset` option and its relatives like in the example below:

```
\setupwhitespace[big]

\definetextbackground[blockquote][
  location=paragraph,
  style=italicbold,
  backgroundcolor=lightgray,
  leftoffset=1em,
  rightoffset=1em,
  topoffset=1em,
  bottomoffset=1em,
  width=\textwidth,
  frame=off,
  ]

\starttext
\startcolumns[n=2, rule=on]

\input douglas

\startblockquote
\input lorem
\stopblockquote

\input knuth

\stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

I'm not sure if you would like the blockquote text offset or not, but if you just want to make the blockquote width match the paragraph, remove the `backgroundoffset`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am avoiding the use of `bottomoffset` and consorts because of the lack of any offset margin at the bottom of column breaks. If you could resolve _that issue,_ this would be a valid answer. Currently, it is not.

Comment: I added a picture of the column break without any offset. This is the problem with this answer.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt Oh I understand what you mean, I just don't know how to help with that unfortunately. I had naively assumed that the problem was relatively simple. I did try to play around with a couple of options, but I'm at a loss. The only thing I can add is that you might be dealing with XY problem here... The fundamental issue seems to be that bottomoffset doesn't respect page/column breaks. That might be worth a separate question on the mailing list.